Generate all n-tuples of array values in Presto SQL
I have the following dataset in Presto.
WITH A (name, distinct_values) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('color', ARRAY['red', 'yellow']),
    ('shape', ARRAY['triangle', 'square', 'circle']),
    ('size', ARRAY['big', 'small'])
)
select * from A

which looks like:



name
distinct_values




color
red,yellow


shape
triangle,square,circle


size
big,small



I don't know how many distinct values are in name or distinct_values ahead of time. What I want is a map column where each row has 3 entries, one for each possible combination of color, shape, and size.
tuples
{'color': 'red', 'shape': 'triangle', 'size': 'big'}
{'color': 'red', 'shape': 'triangle', 'size': 'small'}
{'color': 'red', 'shape': 'square', 'size': 'big'}
...
{'color': 'yellow', 'shape': 'circle', 'size': 'small'}

I can't figure out how to do this in the case where the distinct names are not known ahead of time. Any ideas?


I don't know how many distinct values are in name


I want is a map column where each row has 3 entries, one for each possible combination of color, shape, and size.

Arguably those two requirements kind of contradict each other (though if you are interested only in 3 values in names you can filter all others out).
Based on my understanding of the task - you can try to using CROSS JOIN:
WITH A (name, distinct_values) AS (
  VALUES
    ('color', ARRAY['red', 'yellow']),
    ('shape', ARRAY['triangle', 'square', 'circle']),
    ('size', ARRAY['big', 'small'])
),
-- query parts
 b as (
select name, value
from a
 , unnest(distinct_values) as t (value)
)

select cast(row(b_color.value, b_shape.value, b_size.value) as row(color varchar, shape varchar, size varchar ))
from b b_color
cross join b as b_shape
cross join b as b_size
where b_color.name = 'color' AND b_shape.name = 'shape' AND b_size.name = 'size';

Output:



_col0




{color=red, shape=triangle, size=big}


{color=red, shape=square, size=big}


{color=red, shape=circle, size=big}


{color=red, shape=triangle, size=small}


{color=red, shape=square, size=small}


{color=red, shape=circle, size=small}


{color=yellow, shape=triangle, size=big}


{color=yellow, shape=square, size=big}


{color=yellow, shape=circle, size=big}


{color=yellow, shape=triangle, size=small}


{color=yellow, shape=square, size=small}


{color=yellow, shape=circle, size=small}



Note that this will be a quite taxing query for any input of significant size (though potentially you can optimize it a bit, for example doing filtering before doing the cartesian product)


Arguably those two requirements kind of contradict each other

perhaps I could have written this more clearly. Name has n distinct values. I want the maps to have n keys. I don't necessarily know what n is ahead of time. So this doesn't work because I need to cross join n times
